# Window.reload error is showing after clicking

Tags: javascript

In our webpage, after clicking, it should be reload and I use `window.location.reload` to make that happens. But in developer tool, it's saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'reload') in javascript`. Is there anyway to fix?

```
echo"<FONT color=\"#FF0000\" class=\"ft10\" onClick = \"SetName('".$site."','".$scan4data."','".$hwid."','".$un."','".$hwde."','".$hwlocde."');\" ><b>$barc</b></FONT></a><br>\n";

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "  function SetName(site, scan4data, hwid, un, hwde, hwlocde){";
//, scan4data, hwid, un, hwde, hwlocde, txthwlocde;
//echo "{\n";
echo " var locname= hwlocde; ";
echo " var site2= document.getElementById('site1').value; ";
echo " var txthwlocde = site2 + locname;";

echo " window.location.reload('scantheid.php?site='+ site2 + '&scan4data=' + scan4data + '&hwid=' + hwid + '&un=' + un + '&hwde=' + hwde + '&hwlocde=' + hwlocde + '&txthwlocde=' + txthwlocde);";
//echo " alert ('scantheid.php?site='+ site + '&scan4data=' + scan4data + '&hwid=' + hwid + '&un=' + un + '&hwde=' + hwde + '&hwlocde=' + hwlocde + '&txthwlocde=' + txthwlocde);";
//echo " console.log(txthwlocde);";
echo "window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close()";
echo "    }";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What is the point to echo hardcoded JS to the page? Notice also, that [location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: @Teemu it was written by the previous person and  it is too old. Also, location.reload doesn't take any parameters < according to that, How can I fix ?

Comment: Probably you need to set [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) instead of calling `reload`. See also [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks for your ideas.